# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virualenv (from versions: none) during the installation of beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, pip

I've tried to install beautifulsoup on my system using the command `pip install beautifulsoup4` but it didn't worked as expected and gave me the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bs4
(from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for bs4
```

Comment: Which python version are you running and which OS do you have? Also please post the full error message you are getting

Answer (score 5):

I used the pip install bs4 command.
it works.
Note: For Python 3.9.6

Answer (score 2):

Update pip with `pip3 install --upgrade` pip. Now you should be able to install beautifulsoup `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` or `pip3 install bs4`. If that fails try: `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: bs4 got installed but i'm facing an error while installing requests package and the error is " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.22.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.22.0)"..could you please provide the solution

Comment: @Padmajasrinivasan you question was about `beautifulsoup` not `requests`